# writing and appending into xls file php

Tags: php

Here I am putting some array content into xls file. I want to append some other message to. how it could be done?

currently it writes only array result into file.

I want to write

```
echo $category;
```

Inside for:

```
echo "<br/><br/><strong> $i star word count </strong>";
```

full code

```
        $file = fopen("words.xls","w+");
        echo $category;
        for($i = 5; $i > 0 ; $i--)
        {
            $select_words = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from review_details where rate = $i and category = '".$category."' and isApi = 0");
            while ($row1 = @mysqli_fetch_array($select_words))
            {
                //echo $row1[review]."<br>";
    //          echo $row1[rate]."<br>";
                $word.=$row1[adjective].",";        
            }
            //echo "Words are : $word";
            echo "<br/><br/><strong> $i star word count </strong>";
            $word_count = array_count_values(str_word_count($word,1));
            arsort($word_count);
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";
            //var_dump($word_count);
            $word_count2 = array_slice($word_count,0,20);
            print_r($word_count2);

            unset($word);
            unset($word_count);
            unset($select_words);
            file_put_contents('words.xls', print_r($word_count2, true), FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        }
```

Comment: That is *so* not an XLS file you're producing there.

Comment: words.xls is there dude

Comment: Just because you name the file .xls doesn't mean you're producing a Microsoft Excel format file. Just because Excel tries to read your garbage and comes up with some result anyway doesn't mean your .xls file is actually a Microsoft Excel format file.

Comment: dear deceze, you might be right. actually it creates file named words.xls, which contains data written as per code. SO I am ok with it. problem is different here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend directly opening xls file in php and write values to it, as it will create comparability issues.

If you want to manipulate xls files you can use a free and open source library like PHPExcel.

[URL for PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

The code will look like this:

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("05featuredemo.xlsx");    
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B8', 'Some value');
```

Comment: @EOF: Well its not actually a trick, just a use of PHPExcel's APIs